# Angular2, want some help in checkbox,

Tags: angular

I am getting stuck in development, I have several checkbox at view part, this all are coming from dynamic file

These are the input type checkbox which are creating dynamic.
Master data for all checkbox

```
{
    "data" : [
        { "id": "1" , "value": "xyz" },
        { "id": "2" , "value": "abc" },
        { "id": "3" , "value": "abc1" },
        { "id": "4" , "value": "abc2" },
        { "id": "5" , "value": "abc3" },
        { "id": "6" , "value": "abc4" },
        { "id": "7" , "value": "abc5" }
    ]
}
```

These should come checkked

```
[
{
    "id":"1","name":"xyz"
},
{
    "id":"2","name":"abc"
}
]
```

code at template

```
<div class="ListSection" *ngFor="let why of whyClassification">
    <p> {{why.value}} </p>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="why_{{why.id}}" value="{{why.id}}" checked="confirmAvailability(why.id,'why')">
        <label></label>
    </div
</div>
```

I have tried with adding function in it but it is not getting call during view creation, is there any view that I can achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The template syntax for binding a property (such as checked) to a expression in Angular 2 is brackets.

```
<div class="ListSection" *ngFor="let why of whyClassification">
  <p> {{why.value}} </p>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="why_{{why.id}}" [value]="why.id" [checked]="confirmAvailability(why.id,'why')">
      <label></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to initialize the checked field to true. 
Your code should be something like this :

```
   <div class="ListSection" *ngFor="let why of whyClassification">
        <p> {{why.value}} </p>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
            <input data-ng-if="why.id == '1' || why.id == '2'" "type="checkbox" id="why_{{why.id}}" value="{{why.id}}" checked="true">
            <input data-ng-if="why.id != '1' || why.id != '2'" "type="checkbox" id="why_{{why.id}}" value="{{why.id}}" checked="false">
            <label></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```